# Number of rows decreased on applying the predict function

Tags: r, predict

I am having some trouble with the following code:

```
model4 = glm(data = data16, Loan_Status_Coded ~ Coapplicant_Income_Modified +
Dependents_SelfEmployed_1 + Dependents_Imputed_0_Dummy + 
Dependents_Imputed_1_Dummy + Dependents_Imputed_2_Dummy+ 
Self_Employed_Imputed_Coded + Credit_History_Married + Married_Imputed_Coded + 
sqrt_LoanAmount_Imputed + Loan_Amount_Term_Imputed_Low_Dummy + 
Loan_Amount_Term_Imputed_Medium_Dummy + Credit_History_Imputed + 
Education_Coded + Property_Area_Semiurban_Dummy + Property_Area_Rural_Dummy, 
family = binomial(link = "logit"))

summary(model4)
predict5 = predict(data = data16, model4, type = "response")
table(data16$Loan_Status_Coded, predict5>0.5)
```

Running the `table` function gives the following error:
"all arguments must have the same length"
It seems the number of rows in predict5 is less than the number of rows in data16.
If I use predict5 = predict(newdata = data16, model4, type = "response"), then the error does not occur, but the number of data points decreases. For instance the output on using newdata is:

```
FALSE TRUE
   0    40   39
   1     7  176
```

but `data16` has 614 rows.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any `NA` values in your input?

Comment: No, all the NA values have already been imputed.

Comment: try `predict(model4, newdata=data16, type="response")`

Comment: Using newdata = data16 has dealt with the error, but the number of rows has decreased. The output is this:
 FALSE TRUE
  0    40   39
  1     7  176

data16 originally had 614 rows

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?  Can you edit your question to incorporate the correction/new information in the comments?

Comment: try `table(data16$Loan_Status_Coded, predict5>0.5,useNA="always")` ?  Are you *sure* there are no `NA` values in `data16` ?

Comment: Thank you so much! There indeed were NA values. The culprit was in a variable "CoapplicantIncome" in data16. It's working now.

Comment: You can post an answer your own question, then (you may have to wait a little while before the system lets you do so), or delete it ...

Answer (score 1):

The culprit here was "NA" values in one of the variables in data16. It's working fine after dealing with the "NA" values.